V2O5 in organic chemistry
How can V2O5 convert toluene to benzaldehyde? I read it somewhere but I did not understand why it forms benzaldehyde.

This is the first I'm hearing of this, usually toluene is converted to benzaldehyde by something like the Étard reaction. Could you provide a source for the conversion using $\ce{V2O5}$?

@Sonder It's a misunderstanding, V2O5 is a common catalyst, not oxidiser.

It's partial oxidation and V2O5 is the catalyst here usually incorporated with nanomaterials and metal oxides for increased efficiency.

The first report appears to be this paper in Industrial and Engineering Chemistry (1941) 891

The direct vapor-phase catalytic oxidation
of toluene in the presence of various solid
catalysts to produce benzaldehyde and benzoic acid has been investigated. Vanadium
pentoxide prepared by the decomposition of
ammonium metavanadate at temperatures
below 300' C. was the most satisfactory
catalyst. The effect. of temperature, time
of contact, air/toluene ratio and concentration of vanadium pentoxide on Alfrax,
granular aluminum, and silica gel was
measured.
The highest yields of partial oxidation
products were obtained with vanadium pentoxide supported on Alfrax at temperatures
between 380' and 460' C., time of contact 0.5
second, and air/toluene ratio above 25.

This more recent paper and the references cited should shed more light on this reaction.
As this is a surface-catalysed reaction with O2 I would assume oxygen radicals are generated as the reactive species
